# How to susbcribe to a telemetry events using MQTT and using C code?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

How to susbcribe to a telemetry events using MQTT and using C code?  (this is a microcontroller code)
I can send data to a specified topic but when I trying to subscribe to this topic I got error message

This is the message from the log
 "mqttTopic": "/devices/my-device/events/my_telem_topic1",

This is the error message from the log
 "message": "SUBSCRIBE: Failed to subscribe to topic: '/devices/my-device/events/my_telem_topic1'."

Answer (score 3):

To add to what Kamal posted:

Part of the confusion here is that both MQTT and Pub/Sub (where IoT Core puts your device's telemetry events) are called "topics".

There are 4 MQTT topics for devices to work with (this is all on device side, not Cloud side):

```
/devices/<device-id>/commands
/devices/<device-id>/config
/devices/<device-id>/state
/devices/<device-id>/events
```

The first two are there for devices to subscribe to in order to get updates from the IoT Core Admin SDK, the latter two are topics for device to publish data to the Cloud.

In order for a device to subscribe to another device's telemetry, it would need to be able to subscribe to the Pub/Sub topic that's receiving telemetry from the other device. This won't be done as part of the MQTT implementation, but rather, you'd need to implement the Pub/Sub API on your device. This is going to require a separate authentication path as well, likely a service account key that you add to your GCP project, then download to your device. The links in Kamal's answer should get you started if you want to go down that route.

Depending on what you're doing however, as they say, you can probably process the incoming telemetry from one device in a Cloud Function or similar, then set a config for the device that wants to be responsive to that telemetry. That way, if the device is online, it'll get it right away, or if it's not online, it'll get it upon reconnecting to IoT Core.

Answer (score 2):

Telemetry events sent to Cloud IoT are sent to a [Cloud Pub/Sub topic](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) that is [configured when the device registry is created](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#creating_a_device_registry) and are not intended to be retrieved via MQTT on devices. One could use any of the mechanisms available in Google Cloud to subscribe to these messages ([Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/), [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/), or a [custom-written subscriber](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber)). [Commands](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/commands) can be received by devices via MQTT. The topic for a device's commands is `/devices/{device-id}/commands/#`. [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/commands#sending_a_command) are available to send commands to devices.

One would generally send telemetry events from devices, analyze them with one of the aforementioned Cloud products, and then possibly generate commands to devices based on the results of that analysis.